# I want to make a sound play starting from the 15th second

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, seektotime

I want to make a sound play starting from the 15th second.
How can I do it programmatically?
Thanks!

Comment: No. I want to sound began to play with 15 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "with 15 seconds"? Do you mean you want a delay before it plays? Do you mean you want it to play for 15 seconds and then stop? Etc... Also, explain what you have tried and show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand you are trying to start your audio not from the beginning. In this case:

**You need to use seekToTime**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://www.ringtonemobi.com/storage/upload/user_id_1/iphone-5-alarm-2016-08-21-01-49-25.mp3")!
        player = AVPlayer(url: audioUrl)
        player.seek(to: .init(seconds: 15, preferredTimescale: 1))
        player.play()
    }
}
```